# объединить 4 функции js

Tags: javascript, функции, hide

Как правильно сделать из этих 4-х функций одну?

А также необходимо заставить их работать при нажатии кнопки(теги `button` и `input`) в `html` с помощью атрибута `"onclick=function()"`. Не могу понять как их правильно связать.

```
function showHideVysotskiy() {
    var hideShow = document.getElementById('vysotskiy');
    if (hideShow.style.display === "none"){
        hideShow.style.display = "inline";
    }else{
        hideShow.style.display = "none";
    }
};
function showHideDdt() {
    var hideShow = document.getElementById('ddt');
    if (hideShow.style.display === "none"){
        hideShow.style.display = "inline";
    }else{
        hideShow.style.display = "none";
    }
};
function showHideKeno() {
    var hideShow = document.getElementById('keno');
    if (hideShow.style.display === "none"){
        hideShow.style.display = "inline";
    }else{
        hideShow.style.display = "none";
    }
};
function showHideCinemaSongs() {
    var hideShow = document.getElementById('cinemaSongs');
    if (hideShow.style.display === "none"){
        hideShow.style.display = "inline";
    }else{
        hideShow.style.display = "none";
    }
};
```

Я пробовал самостоятельно как-то так, но не понимаю как обозначить номер переменной `i` при исполнении `"onclick="function()""` :

```
var x = {
    vysotskiy: document.getElementById('vysotskiy'), 
    ddt: document.getElementById('ddt'), 
    keno: document.getElementById('keno'), 
    cinemaSongs: document.getElementById('cinemaSongs')
};
var i = x.length;
function showHide() {
    if (x[i].style.display === "none"){
        x[i].style.display = "inline";
    }else{
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
};
```

Comment: что именно в итоге должно получиться? одна функция которая скрывает только один элемент, но ее можно вызвать для любого элемента, или функция которая скрывает сразу все элементы?

Comment: одна функция, которая скрывает только один элемент, но ее можно вызвать для любого элемента @Grundy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как функции отличаются только элементом, id его можно передать через параметр

```
function showHide(hideShowId) {
    var hideShow = document.getElementById(hideShowId)
    if (hideShow.style.display === "none"){
        hideShow.style.display = "inline";
    }else{
        hideShow.style.display = "none";
    }
};
```

и вызывать потом

```
onclick='showHide("ddt")'
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Answer (score 3):

```
function showHide() {
    ['vysotskiy', 'ddt', 'keno', 'cinemaSongs'].forEach(function(id){
        var element = document.getElementById(id);
        if (element.style.display === "none"){
            element.style.display = "inline";
        }else{
            element.style.display = "none";
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: `document.getElementById` можно было и в функции оставить :-)

Comment: ну ок, щас исправлю

Comment: да не обязательно на самом деле :-) это так, заметка на полях :)

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то это можно сделать, например, так:

```
function showHide(id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    if (elem != null)
        elem.style.display = (elem.style.display === "none") ? "inline" : "none";
}
var ids = ['vysotskiy', 'ddt', 'keno', 'cinemaSongs'];
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; ++i)
    showHide(ids[i]);
```

Если можно использовать *ECMAScript 5*, то цикл можно заменить методом `forEach`:

```
ids.forEach(showHide)
```